# hibernate - many-to-many with join table, sql query not joining

Tags: hibernate, join, many-to-many, inner-join

I have the following two POJOs:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"identifier"})
@ToString(of={"identifier"})
public class Project {
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer identifier;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "primaryKey.project")
    private Set<MemberToProject> members = new HashSet<MemberToProject>();
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"identifier"})
@ToString(of={"identifier"})
public class Member {
    @Column
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer identifier;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "primaryKey.member")
    private Set<MemberToProject> projects = new HashSet<MemberToProject>();
}
```

The POJO for the join table is as following:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class MemberToProject {
    @Embeddable
    @Data
    public static class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne
        private Member member;

        @ManyToOne
        private Project project;
    }

    @Column
    @EmbeddedId
    private PrimaryKey primaryKey;
}
```

I want a separate POJO for the join table, so I can add properties, such as the date on which the member joined the project, the permissions of the member, etc. I left that out for brevity.

I filled my database with some data and execute the following code:

```
final Session s = ...;
final Member m = (Member) s.load(Member.class, 3);

System.out.println(m.getProjects());
```

Hibernate generates the following three queries:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        member0_.identifier as identifi1_1_0_,
        member0_.name as name2_1_0_ 
    from
        Member member0_ 
    where
        member0_.identifier=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        projects0_.member_identifier as member1_1_1_,
        projects0_.member_identifier as member1_4_1_,
        projects0_.project_identifier as project2_4_1_,
        projects0_.member_identifier as member1_4_0_,
        projects0_.project_identifier as project2_4_0_ 
    from
        MemberToProject projects0_ 
    where
        projects0_.member_identifier=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        project0_.identifier as identifi1_6_0_,
        project0_.name as name2_6_0_ 
    from
        Project project0_ 
    where
        project0_.identifier=?
```

Hibernate generates inefficient queries here. There is no join between *project* and *member* in *membertoproject*. I believe that the second and the third queries could/should be combined. How can I achieve this?

Also, the second query retrieves the same column several times, for some reason I do not understand.

Comment: The annotations `@Data`, `@EqualsAndHashCode` and `@ToString` are from project Lombok.

Answer (score 0):

I think, The relationships between 'Member' and 'Project' is ManyToMany.

Try it

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"identifier"})
@ToString(of={"identifier"})
public class Project {
@Column(name="PROJECT_ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer projectId;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "projects")
private Set<MemberToProject> members = new HashSet<MemberToProject>();
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"identifier"})
@ToString(of={"identifier"})
public class Member {
@Column(name="MEMBER_ID")
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer memberId;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name="MEMBER_PROJECT", 
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MEMBER_ID")})
private Set<MemberToProject> projects = new HashSet<MemberToProject>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The relation is indeed ManyToMany, but I want a separate POJO for the join table, so I can add properties there. For example the date when the member joined the project, the permissions, ... I did not include that in my question for brevity.

Comment: No problem. Your response is very much appreciated.